# Check if a digit is present in a list of numbers

Tags: python, integer, contains

How can I see if a number contains certain digits?

```
numbers = [2349523234, 12345123, 12346671, 13246457, 134123431]

for number in numbers:
    if (4 in number):
        print(number + "True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would have to do string comparisons for this

```
for number in numbers:
    if '4' in str(number):
        print('{} True'.format(number))
    else:
        print('{} False'.format(number))
```

It isn't really meaningful to ask if the number `4` is "in" another number (unless you have some particular definition of "in" in mind)

Answer (score 6):

You can convert the number to string and if you want to get the first number that has `4` in it you can use a generator expression within `next`:

```
>>> next(i for i in numbers if '4' in str(i))
2349523234
```

Or you can use a list comprehension if you want to preserve the number that satisfy the condition:

```
expected_numbers=[i for i in numbers if '4' in str(i)]
```

But from a mathematical point of view you can generate all the digits using following function:

```
In [1]: def decomp(num):
   ...:     while num:
   ...:         yield num % 10
   ...:         num = num // 10
```

Then you can do the following:

```
In [3]: numbers = [2349523234, 12345123, 12346671, 13246457, 134123431]

In [4]: [n for n in numbers if any(4==i for i in decomp(n))]
Out[4]: [2349523234, 12345123, 12346671, 13246457, 134123431]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number=[number for number in numbers if '4' in str(numbers)]
print(number)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Klist = []
count = 0
while count < 1000:
    count += 1
    Klist.append(count)
for k in Klist:
    if '6' in str(k):
        print(k)
```

You create the list and then iterate through the numbers but as a string.