# How to get elements in the list starting with some given condtion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My code is:

```
 b=[1215316235,1215316234,1210216096,1210716053]
 for i in range(398):
    a=b[i]
    if a[0:5] == '12153':
        print(a)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-d3b104ffc744> in <module>()
  1 for i in range(398):
  2     a=b[i]
 ----> 3     if a[0:5] == '12153':
  4         print(a)

  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I get my expected output:

```
1215316235
1215316234
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a digit is present in a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769699/check-if-a-digit-is-present-in-a-list-of-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your logic to work, you need to convert to `str` before slicing. In addition, you should iterate over values rather than a range, for example by slicing your list.

A more efficient approach is to use a list comprehension. Here are some examples:

```
b = [1215316235, 1215316234, 1210216096, 1210716053]

import math

b = b*10000

%timeit [x[:5] == '12153' for x in map(str, b)]                # 22.4 ms per loop
%timeit [str(x)[:5] == '12153' for x in b]                     # 28.1 ms per loop
%timeit [x // 10**(int(math.log10(x))-4) == 12153 for x in b]  # 48.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `b`, a list of integers, to a list of strings first:

```
b = [1215316235, 1215316234, 1210216096, 1210716053]
c = map(str, b)
for i in range(398):
    a = c[i]
    if a[0:5] == '12153':
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go over indices once you type cast an `int` into a `str`.

```
b = [1215316235, 1215316234, 1210216096, 1210716053]
for i in map(str, b):
    if i[:5] == '12153':
        # this is a str; if you want an int change for spec above
        print(i)
```

I would personally add this into a function and remove the hardcoded number there; although that's solely up to you and how you need to use it.